# What are the optimal conditions for the complete acid hydrolysis (using HCl) of potato starch?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, concentration, carbohydrates, hydrolysis

I'm hoping someone can provide the specifics on the optimal conditions required for the complete acid hydrolysis (using $\ce{HCl}$) of potato starch?

I will be using an autoclave (~$\pu{15 psi}$ @ $\pu{120 degrees Celsius}$) to facilitate hydrolysation.

Specifically I'm after for the following information:

- Concentration of dry starch required for the starch slurry.
- Concentration of $\ce{HCl}$ required to adjust $\pu{pH}$ to required level.
- What is the required $\pu{pH}$ for hydrolysation?
- Time required to complete hydrolysation under above autoclave conditions.

Plus anything else that I may have missed....

Thanks!

Comment: I have suggested some MathJax to make your post look a little prettier.

Comment: If you are able to measure the amount of the starch you hydrolized, why not to make some experiements to find by yourself your process' variables? You can make a little design experiment or just two or three experiments with a fixed volumes of starch and different volumes of HCl and then compare and try to find something optimum.